# How to use double to imitate objects and mock instance method calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method in a controller helper

```
def method
    @user = User.join(:something).where('some condition').first
    if @user.present?
       method_present
    else
       method_blank
end
```

In RSpec test case,

```
User.stub_chain(:joins, :where, :first) {double}
# expect(helper).to receive(:method_blank) or otherwise
```

However, with this condition, @user.present? is always returning true. How can I make it return false?

Answer (score 0):

`before { allow_any_instance_of(User).to_receive(:present?) { false } }`